Hosting MS Orleans 7.0 on .NET 4.8
I understand that Orleans and Microsoft.Hosting both work with .NET Standard 2.0 which is supported by .NET 4.8
See: Run Anywhere
For reference, I have already viewed this question which answers "Can Orleans be hosted in ASP.NET framework" but it does not answer HOW?: Is it possible to run Microsoft Orleans in classic ASP.NET MVC 4
Is there an example of hosting and consuming Orleans from .NET 4.8 using ASP.NET ?

where to initialize?
using the Microsoft.Hosting in an IIS hosted ASP.NET app?


Orleans 7.x requires .NET 7, you need to go back to Orleans 3.x to use it with .NET Framework (via .NET Standard).

@Karl-JohanSjögren not sure if this means anything but see their statement on 'runs anywhere' https://github.com/dotnet/orleans?tab=readme-ov-file#run-anywhere

Then that is either outdated information or they refer to using the older version on .NET Framework. If you look at the nuget package for 7.0.0 it says .net7.0 as the only supported framework. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Orleans.Core/7.0.0#supportedframeworks-body-tab

That "RunsAnywhere" does not say it runs on any framework. It says, it runs "anywhere that .NET Core or .NET Framework are supported". And it even gives examples:  "This includes hosting on Linux, Windows, and macOS and deploying to Kubernetes, [...]"

@jensG the promise was runs anywhere net standard 2.0 is used which includes core and framework. it's implied. it's just an outdated statement that needs to be updated

You can if you split your front (ASP.net MVC) and MS Orleans cluster.
Your ASP.net MVC 4 run as client (With a client FROM Orleans 3+) for a .net7+ MS Orleans cluster.
The other advantage if you will be able to scale the cluster without scaling your "Facade" (front).
It's like your ASP.NET MVC 4 app act as reverse proxy or simple API front.
